# foreign key consraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE VideoDataView
(
Game_id  INT NOT NULL,
Vid_id INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Vid_id),
FOREIGN KEY (Game_id) REFERENCES Game(Game_id),
Vid_firstHalf VARCHAR(50),
Vid_secondHalf VARCHAR(50)
);
```

It says foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed can anybody help plz

```
CREATE TABLE Game
(
Game_id VARCHAR(50),
Game_location VARCHAR(50),
Sea_id INT NOT NULL,
Game_date DATE,
Game_conference VARCHAR(50),
FOREIGN KEY (Sea_id) REFERENCES Season(Sea_id),
PRIMARY KEY(Game_id)
);
```

that's the parent table

Comment: "It says" sound like you want to share the full and exact error message, and your attempts to resolve that error

Answer (score 1):

In one table it is

```
Game_id INT
```

in the other

```
Game_id VARCHAR(50)
```

You have to use the same data type.